# Wanting to write units properly

Tags: units

Could anyone explain how I write units properly in LaTeX? In the form `kg.s^-1`. They come out all slanted and squished together when i use math mode and `\frac`.

Comment: `siunitx` package definitely.

Comment: Do I have to download that? I mean, I'm completely new to LaTeX.

Comment: Try `\si{kg.s^{-1}}` by loading the package `siunitx`.

Comment: I suppose you have miktex or texlive right? If so then download the  package via the tlmgr(texlive) or package manager(miktex).

Answer (score 27):

The [siunitx](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package will interpret the units correctly

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\noindent%
\si{kg.s^{-1}}\\
\si{\kilogram\per\second} \\
\si[per-mode=symbol]
{\kilogram\per\second}
\end{document}
```